# How to read/write to a text file to store an API response with SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Basically, I am going to have a server POSTing a JSON message to a SvelteKit route, every now and again. I want my SvelteKit route to save that response until it gets a new one, and if there is a GET request to it, to reply with the JSON message it saved.

Before switching to SvelteKit, I achieved this using some simple PHP, which would read and write to a .json file. I really don't want to have to bring a database into this, and I couldn't find a way to write/read to a text file in SvelteKit.

Eventually, my app will run on a Node.js server, but I'd like to not have to make further customisations after the build process is complete.

I am aware I may be going about this the wrong way, and I'm new to server-side Javascript, so thank you for reading thus far.

Comment: What have you tried? You can use all Node APIs on the server, including `fs`.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way I could do it without editing the post-build process files for the sake of version control

Comment: How is that related to version control? Files you create at run-time will not be included in it.

Comment: (You build files should be excluded from version control already.)

Comment: I do not want to include my build files in version control, but I do want to include this API endpoint code.